# Recycle bin - documents deleted

Tags: event-receivers, delete, recycle-bin

I have recycle on my site collection. There is also and event receiver which deletes some documents from library in ElevatedPrivileges block ( as System account). OnItemDeleting it's searching for file and deletes it from library folder.

I can't see these documents unfortunately as site collection administrator in recycle bin. Does file deleted from library folder go to recycle bin, or are they they deleted completely?

Answer (score 2):

Goto central admin - application managment - manage web application - select web application - then select general

[image]

setting to on = having the second stage bin on for site collection admins only!

setting to off = no second stage bin.

If you have it on:

select after x ammount of days and click on add x ammount of percent. check to see the quota and if the file exceeds that quota, meaning it gets deleted from the second stage as its surpassed the max limmit.

Also for clarification! just because your site admin doesnt mean you have access to client bin ;)

> Even though you are the site administrator, when you access the
> recycle bin from "Quick Links" section, What you get to see is:
> End-user recycle bin, which is security trimmed (meaning, You will not
> see items deleted by other users!).   To view All the items in
> End-User recycle bins (Items deleted by all end-users), Go to site
> settings page >> Recycle bin under Site Collection Administration
> where you will get the End user Recycle Bin items (Which is actually
> Administrator's recycle bin with all deleted items of all users. It is
> the First stage recycle bin) and "Deleted from end user Recycle Bin"
> (which is nothing but 2nd Stage recycle bin).
>
> URL Shortcuts for accessing Recycle bin: After the SharePoint Site URL
> (say: http://company.sharepoint.com/) append:
>
> •/_layouts/recyclebin.aspx  - For End User Recycle Bin
>
> •/_layouts/AdminRecycleBin.aspx - For Site collection Administrator
> Recycle bin.

Read more:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/sharepoint-recycle-bins-lets-get-it.html#ixzz2IE2jKoVq

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if your recycle bin status wasn't on then file or document you delete is permanently deleted however also if change its status to off from on it empties all of recycle bin which happened to me once and I couldn't recover document back, however I find this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151009170118/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2007/09/14/how-to-recover-sharepoint-document-once-deleted-from-recycle-bin.aspx) that is claiming you can recover document back.

However if you need more information about recycle bin,

> The recycle bin in SharePoint is synonymous to Recycle bin in windows
> and helps the users in recovering files which have been deleted
> accidentally.
>
> The files in the recycle bin can either be recovered or can be deleted
> after a pre defined period of time.
>
> Recycle Bin Stages
>
> SharePoint supports two levels of Recycle bin. The initial or First
> level Recycle bin comes in picture when the user deletes an item from
> a list. Once the item is deleted again from the First level of Recycle
> bin it moves to the second stage of Recycle bin.

[image]

> Item not available in Recycle Bin
>
> If you try to find an item in the recycle bin and fail to locate it
> then you need to verify the following :
>
> The contents in the recycle bin are driven by the access control. The
> user who has deleted the content will be able to see the content in
> the recycle bin. Other users will not be able to see the items in the
> recycle bin. If you have deleted a top level item like a folder or a
> list, and try to find a document available at an inner location, then
> the item will not be viewable. By default the Recycle bin shows the
> top level content and does not have the capability to show the items
> in a tree structure or drill down mode. The contents in the recycle
> bin contains only the items within the site. A deleted site is outside
> the scope of the Recycle bin and is not available for deletion. The
> recycle bin contains the items for a pre defined period which can be
> set from the Web Application –> General Settings. if the thresh hold
> is crossed, the item is deleted permanently.

For More Information check this [link](https://sharepointtech.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/sharepoint-2010-recycle-bin/) OR this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170409161525/http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1064) out.